# Define [sql2016] as [sql-server-2016]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

Please merge [sql2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql2016) to [sql-server-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2016). It has only 2 questions now ;).

Edit:
[sql2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql2008) is synonym of  [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008), and because of that I suggest this.

Comment: Does this need to be a synonym? Why not just edit those 2 questions?

Comment: I've re-tagged both questions, so they should be cleaned up the next time the cleanup script runs.

Comment: Eh, there are a number of these synonyms that exist for other versions, like you said, so I went ahead and created this one. It's not like having a synonym really hurts anything. And if it does, it can be just as easily removed.